# if statement being ignored within the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm writing a basic for loop where all the output should be the same except for the last row. However, my if statement just keeps getting ignored, even though the condition is `TRUE`.

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")

i <- 1
for(i in length(test_string)) {
  answer <- if(i < length(test_string)) {
    paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string, "%'")

  } else{
    paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string, "%'")
  }
  i <- i+1
}

#> [1] "This IS the LAST '%test%'"  "This IS the LAST '%test2%'"
#> [3] "This IS the LAST '%test3%'"
```

Comment: `length(.)` always returns a scalar, e.g., `3` in this case, it never returns a vector, so the `for` loop only iterates over a single value.

Comment: Perhaps you mean ``for(i in 1:length(test_string))``...

Answer (score 5):

Try to add seq_along() to the first line. Like this:

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")

for(i in seq_along(test_string)) {
  answer <- if(i < length(test_string)) {
    paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string[i], "%'")
  } else{
    paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string[i], "%'")
  }
  print(answer)
}
#[1] "This is not the last '%test%'"
#[1] "This is not the last '%test2%'"
#[1] "This IS the LAST '%test3%'"
```

To store the output as a variable:

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")
answers <- c()

for(i in seq_along(test_string)) {
  answer <- if(i < length(test_string)) {
    paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string[i], "%'")
  } else{
    paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string[i], "%'")
  }
  answers <- c(answers, answer)
}

# View the results
answers
```

Comment: I'm surprised so many others suggested `1:length(test_string)`.  Only you got it right!  Congratulations.  Your code is likely to work reliably, theirs won't for some `test_string` settings.

Comment: @user2554330 it's not wrong or right, just different. Posting the same thing is not helpful, so better to have different options. I am curious about the settings that the other options won't work. Care to share an example?

Comment: @M--:  `test_string <- character()` will not work properly with `1:length(test_string)`.  This is the reason you should rarely use `1:length(...)`.  It works in quick testing, but fails in this one unusual case.

Comment: @user2554330 Empty vecotr?? Well, you are not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Because `i` is always `3` inside the loop.

To see this, add `print(i)` as the first line of the loop.

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")

i <- 1
for(i in length(test_string)) {
  print(i) # New
  answer <- if(i < length(test_string)) {
    paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string, "%'")
    
  } else{
    paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string, "%'")
  }
  i <- i+1
}

# Output: [1] 3
```

I would then remove as much code as possible, while still retaining the error. When I do that here, I wind up with this:

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")
for(i in length(test_string)) {
  print(i)
}

# Output: [1] 3
```

Literally the only thing left we can do here is put `length(test_string)` into the console:

```
> length(test_string)
[1] 3
```

That is, you are not really "looping" at all. You are setting `i` to a single value (3) and then running a single block of code once. You probably meant to write `1:length(test_string)`

```
> 1:length(test_string)
[1] 1 2 3
```

So when I update the `for` loop with this new expression, I think I get the result you originally expected:

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")

i <- 1
for(i in 1:length(test_string)) {
  print(i) # New
  answer <- if(i < length(test_string)) {
    paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string, "%'")
    
  } else{
    paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string, "%'")
  }
  i <- i+1
}

# Output
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

Comment: You gave a nice explanation, but your code is wrong in a couple of ways.  You didn't select `test_string[i]`, you worked with the whole string every time.  And the `i <- i + 1` is unnecessary.

Comment: @user2554330 I believe that I copied his code verbatim, and then made the smallest number of changes to answer his primary question (the title of the question is "if statement being ignored within the for loop"). There might very well be multiple issues with the original code. But when it comes to answering SO questions, I like to focus on just a single thing.

Answer (score 0):

You've just forgot the two things:
`1:` before length in `for` clausedeclaration and `[i]` to access elements of test_string:

```
test_string <- c("test", "test2", "test3")

i <- 1
for(i in 1:length(test_string)) {
  answer <- if(i < length(test_string)) {
    paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string[i], "%'")

  } else{
    paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string[i], "%'")
  }
  print(answer) 
  i <- i+1
}
```

You get the required result:

```
[1] "This is not the last '%test%'"
[1] "This is not the last '%test2%'"
[1] "This IS the LAST '%test3%'"
```

Howewer i think it is necessary to note that common `for` etc. loops are commonly slower in R. There are plenty of ways to make it in an "Rly" way accessing the values with vectorized functions...

Here is an example in base R:

```
answer2 <- paste0("This is not the last '%", test_string, "%'")

answer2[length(answer)] <- paste0("This IS the LAST '%", test_string[length(answer)], "%'")
answer2
```

This will give you a vector result:

```
[1] "This IS the LAST '%test%'"      "This is not the last '%test2%'"
[3] "This is not the last '%test3%'"
```

This code is shorter and faster and more clear for future edits in R.

Comment: This works in the sample data, but wouldn't work if `test_string` was length 0.  And why keep `i <- i+1`?

Comment: @user2554330 you are right. Nobody of those who gave answers also evaluated other border conditions like NA's as string vector memebers or if test_string did not exist. The reason was that I decided not to change the OP's code more than necessary to make it valid. For the rest I provided a new script.